# Mock DOM event with Angular and Jest

Tags: angular, events, dom, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a DOM Event for a unit test with Jest in Angular and for some reason I can't get it working.

Basically, my component is listening for the animationend event and then doing some stuff.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.addAnimationEndListener();
}

private addAnimationEndListener() {
  this.removeListenerFn = this.renderer.listen(this.element, "animationend", event =>
      this.onEndAnimation(event)
  );
}

private onEndAnimation(event: any) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

This code is working, when the animationend event is fired the onEndAnimation method is called.

Now, my unit test is doing something like this

```
it("should emit an endAnimation output event", done => {
  component.ngAfterViewInit();
  //fixture.detectChanges();
  const event = new Event("animationend");
  Object.assign(event, animationEventMixin("slide-down"));
  dispatchEvent(event);
  component.endAnimation.subscribe(() => done());
});
```

Now, because AnimationEvent is not defined in Jest (JSDOM) I need to use a regular event and add some extra properties, but the event I'm dispatching at the end is a valid event of type "animationend", so it's being dispatched, but the onAnimationEnd method is not being fired.

I'm guessing the issue is now related to Angular itself. Any ideas?

Comment: If using the built-in `dispatchEvent()`, it should be called on an element: `myElement.dispatchEvent(event);` And if using the version imported from `platform-browser`, then the first argument should be the element: `dispatchEvent(myElement, event);`